# Omit rows in all data.frames in list, who don't share a common ID

Tags: r

I have a list, containing several data frames (only 2 in this example) of different sizes.

```
> myList
$`1`
   ID values
1   1    100
2   2    200
3   3    240
4   4    403
5   5    212
6   6    432
7   7    423
8   8    123
9   9    543
10 10    982

$`2`
  ID values
1  3    432
2  5    333
3  6    981
```

Now, I need to omit all row's in any of the data frames that do not share their `ID` in any of the other data frames. In this example, the result I'm looking for is:

```
> myList2
$`1`
   ID values
3   3    240
5   5    212
6   6    432

$`2`
  ID values
1  3    432
2  5    333
3  6    981
```

I've tried to use `dplyr::setequal()` but end up with `FALSE: Different number of rows`. I'd prefer a base solution if possible. Thanks in advance!

Reproducible code:

```
myList <- list(data.frame('ID' = c(1:10), 'values' = c(100,200,240,403,212,432,423,123,543,982)),data.frame('ID' = c(3,5,6), 'values' = c(432,333,981)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way via base R is to use `Reduce(intersect, ...)` to find the common IDs from all data frames in the list. We then use that to index the data frames.

```
ind <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(myList, '[[', 1))

lapply(myList, function(i) i[i$ID %in% ind,])
#[[1]]
#  ID values
#3  3    240
#5  5    212
#6  6    432

#[[2]]
#  ID values
#1  3    432
#2  5    333
#3  6    981
```

Comment: thank you, that worked perfectly in on the example above, but somehow it does not with my actual data:

Comment: `
List of 2
 $ 1:'data.frame': 735 obs. of  53 variables:
  ..$ obsId              : chr [1:735] "15597" "15598" "15599" "15600" ...
  ..$ subjectId          : num [1:735] 2230 2231 2233 2232 2235 ...
  ..$ procedureSampleId  : num [1:735] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...



$ 2:'data.frame': 8 obs. of  53 variables:
  ..$ obsId              : chr [1:8] "15628" "15707" "15828" "15938" ...
  ..$ subjectId          : num [1:8] 2260 2338 2458 2567 2687 ...
  ..$ procedureSampleId  : num [1:8] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
`

Comment: At first i thought this was due to the naming of data.frames, but your code seems to work even though myList contains named data.frames. My output is of 0 rows, but it should be 8

Comment: The code should have worked then assuming those 8 `obsId` of second data frame are indeed in the first. Maybe try to reproduce a data set that gives you the error and update your question.

Comment: I just realized that you were referring to the column nr. by `1` in `ind <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(myList, '[[', 1))`. Changed it to `'subjectId'` which resulted in the wanted outcome. thanks once again:)